# How to determine which program is better based on order of growth?

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity, big-o

The order of growth of the running time of one algorithm is N; the order of growth of the running time of a second algorithm is N^2.

List **TWO** compelling reasons why a programmer would prefer to use the N^2 algorithm instead of the N one.

Comment: The title does not have much common with the question body. Please edit and bring them together.

Comment: That looks a lot like a homework question

Comment: This looks like an exam question. We are not here to help you not learn.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot determine which algorithm is better base on order of growth. Order of growth just describes size of needed resources depend on input data. So there can be a situation where an program with worst complexity is faster, because input data isn't big enough.

For example Java implementation of sorting uses Insertion Sort ( `O(N^2)`)  on small array (i.e. less that 29 elements) and counting sort ( `O(N^2)`) or Quicksort ( `O(Nlog(N))`) on big arrays.

Another example would be using Floyd-Warshall Algorithm ( `O(N^3)`) instead of Dijkstra Algortihm ( `O(E*logV)`) because it has much simpler implementation and doesn't need a priority queue (because we don't have its implementation in every environment)

Answer (score 0):

1. If the actual running times are `C0.N` and `C1.N²` with `C1.N < C0`, it's better to use the "slow" algorithm.
2. Better space complexity.